# RF sniffer with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, rf

Hello programmers out in the world.
I am doing a capstone project for an RF sniffer to capture RF signals from Key fobs within an OEM manufacturing plant. I want to be able to decode this RF signal to show me what the battery state of the key fob is. I have the protocol, so I know what data I should be receiving. However, I have tried many libraries on the Arduino UNO and none have worked.
This Key fob specs are FSK modulation. Frequency of 433 Mhz, Bit rate -> 9.6Kbit/s, baud rate of 19.2Kbaud/s and coding is manchester.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Which libraries have you tried how? Please include one or two simple code examples, that you tried, with the most promising libraries. And are you sure, that you have a fitting receiver module? The datasheet doesn't say 433MHz, but 433.92MHz. Your module might not be tuned to that frequency (433MHz is more a complete band instead of a singe frequency).

Answer (score 1):

I actaully found this this week that I was suing ASK RF receiver module, when I needed FSK.
I have used RC Switch, and no luck, along with Radio head.
However as mentioned the key fob will not work with ASK. I am trying to find a library for FSK but no luck as of now.

-Pete